# Передать из списка listview название rss ленты во второй listview, в котором будут получены заголовок, дата и текст ленты

Tags: android, listview, xmlparser, rss

Нужно передать данные, которые вводятся в edittext и передаются в список Listview. То есть вводится название rss ленты, оно передается в список. По нажатию на элемент списка (название ленты) открывается второе активити, в котором нужно получить данные rss канала.

В активити сделал ввод в listview из edittext'a

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_postlist);


ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.postListView);
final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);


final ArrayList<String> rssNames = new ArrayList<>();


final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, rssNames);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);



    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        rssNames.add(0, editText.getText().toString());
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        editText.setText("");
    }
});
```

}
}

Сделал метод и класс для получения данных для rss ленты

```
public List<RssFeedModel> parseFeed(InputStream inputStream) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    String title = null;
    String link = null;
    String description = null;
    boolean isItem = false;
    List<RssFeedModel> items = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        XmlPullParser xmlPullParser = Xml.newPullParser();
        xmlPullParser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
        xmlPullParser.setInput(inputStream, null);

        xmlPullParser.nextTag();
        while (xmlPullParser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            int eventType = xmlPullParser.getEventType();

            String name = xmlPullParser.getName();
            if(name == null)
                continue;

            if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                    isItem = false;
                }
                continue;
            }

            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                    isItem = true;
                    continue;
                }
            }

            Log.d("MainActivity", "Parsing name ==> " + name);
            String result = "";
            if (xmlPullParser.next() == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                result = xmlPullParser.getText();
                xmlPullParser.nextTag();
            }

            if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                title = result;
            } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("link")) {
                link = result;
            } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("description")) {
                description = result;
            }

            if (title != null && link != null && description != null) {
                if(isItem) {
                    RssFeedModel item = new RssFeedModel(title, link, description);
                    items.add(item);
                }
                else {
                    mFeedTitle = title;
                    mFeedLink = link;
                    mFeedDescription = description;
                }

                title = null;
                link = null;
                description = null;
                isItem = false;
            }
        }

        return items;
    } finally {
        inputStream.close();
    }
}

private class FetchFeedTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    private String urlLink;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mSwipeLayout.setRefreshing(true);
        mFeedTitle = null;
        mFeedLink = null;
        mFeedDescription = null;

        mFeedDescriptionTextView.setText("Feed Description: " + mFeedDescription);
        mFeedLinkTextView.setText("Feed Link: " + mFeedLink);
        urlLink = mEditText.getText().toString();
        mFeedTitleTextView.setText(urlLink);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(urlLink))
            return false;

        try {
            if(!urlLink.startsWith("http://") && !urlLink.startsWith("https://"))
                urlLink = "http://" + urlLink;

            URL url = new URL(urlLink);
            InputStream inputStream = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
            mFeedModelList = parseFeed(inputStream);
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error", e);
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error", e);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean success) {
        mSwipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);

        if (success) {
           mFeedTitleTextView.setText("Feed Title: " + mFeedTitle);
           mFeedDescriptionTextView.setText("Feed Description: " + mFeedDescription);
           mFeedLinkTextView.setText("Feed Link: " + mFeedLink);
            // Fill RecyclerView
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new RssFeedListAdapter(mFeedModelList));
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "Enter a valid Rss feed url",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

}

макет для получения данных rss item_rss_feed.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/titleText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/descriptionText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/linkText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent" />
```

Не знаю, как передать название rss ленты во второе активити, и используя название ленты, во втором активити получить заголовок, ссылку и тело ленты

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте обработчик нажатия на элементы списка. А оттуда передавайте данные в другую активити.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
      int position, long id) {
    String rrsName = rssNames.get(position);
    //метод отправки данных в другое активити 
  }
});
```